# Unable to display docs filtered by a single field

Tags: javascript, meteor

Using a text input, I add docs to a Collections object, each of which contains the text from the text input, and a sess param that holds `Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId` like so: `Links.insert({sess:Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId,youtube_link:url});`

In `myapp.html`, I have:

```
<template name="list_of_links">
   <ul id="item-list">
        {{#each my_playlist}}
            {{> link_item}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="link_item">
<li class="link">
    <div class="link-title">{{youtube_link}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{sess}}</div>
</li>
</template>
```

In `myapp.js`

Under `isClient`, I have:

```
   Meteor.subscribe("links");
    Template.list_of_links.my_playlist = function () {
      //return Links.find({sess: Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId});
      return Links.find();
    };
```

And under `isServer`, I have:

```
Meteor.publish("links", function() {
    //return Links.find({sess:Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId});
    return Links.find();
});
```

Note the *commented* out lines. Without them (as it is right now), the app prints all the elements in the db in the `#each` loop. With the now commented lines (which is the desired behaviour), I want to be able to display the elements in the current browser session in the list, however I do not see anything displayed even though calling: `Links.find({sess:Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId}).fetch()` gives me the desired output...

What is causing this, and do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like at least two problems:

1) I think Meteor.default_connection is not available in the server publish function

2) a cursor where you can fetch the values you expect but where returning the cursor to a template does not display those values sounds like a bug.  Keep in mind you will need to call `.rewind()` on that cursor between fetching the values to check them and returning them in the template.

To fix the first problem the client should subscribe like this:

```
Deps.autorun( function(){
  if ( Meteor.status().connected )
    Meteor.subscribe( "links", Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId);
});
```

And publish on the server like this:

```
Meteor.publish("links", function( sess ) {
  return Links.find({sess: sess});  //each client will only have links with that _lastSessionId
});
```

Then your template helper becomes:

```
Template.list_of_links.my_playlist = function () {
  return Links.find();  //all links client has but client only has links with their _lastSessionId
};
```

I wonder if this will also fix the second problem since it would be a surprising bug.

--Updated code to add a reactive variable to the Deps.autorun.  Without that the autorun will only run once.  Based on comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021013/weird-issue-where-after-inserting-a-doc-it-exists-for-an-instant-and-then-dele#comment29819139_20021446)

Comment: The issue now changes to the element being added to the collections for an instant, displaying the object for an instant, and then it somehow deletes itself.

Comment: It sounds like the client's insert is getting rejected at the server.  Make sure you are have an [allow function](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) on the server.  Without that the default is to reject all client inserts once autopublish is removed.

Comment: correction to the comment above.  It is the 'insecure' package that allows clients to update, insert, and delete documents in the db.