# Weird issue where after inserting a doc, it exists for an instant, and then deletes itself?

Tags: javascript, meteor

They way I'm testing this is a simple for loop in the template to run through the elements available to the client and display them in a list.

I insert the elements through a text input identified by `#query`.

When I enter an element, it displays for a brief instant, and a console log that prints out `Links.find().fetch()` shows that the element exists, and then shortly afterwards, the element is seemingly automagically removed making any successive calls to `Links.find().fetch()` yield an empty list. Is this a bug within Meteor? Or is it expected behaviour and bad implementation?

**UPDATE**

Another weird development, I added `setTimeout(function(){Links.find().fetch()},3000);` to the server side to try and track what was going on. With this line, the inserts work correctly for a while, and then crashes with these errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYNgY.png
. What is going on?

Below is my template file `myapp.html`

```
<head>
  <title>myapp</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> search_bar}}
  <br>
  {{> list_of_links}}
</body>

<template name="search_bar">
    <h1>Playlist</h1>
    <input id="query" type="text" placeholder="Enter Query Here"/>
</template>

<template name="list_of_links">
   <ul id="item-list">
        {{#each my_playlist}}
            {{> link_item}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>

<template name="link_item">
<li class="link">
    <div class="link-title">{{youtube_link}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{sess}}</div>
</li>
</template>
```

And here follows `myapp.js`

```
//Setting up a collection of urls
Links = new Meteor.Collection("links");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  //"Subscribing" to server's published data
    Deps.autorun( function(){
      Meteor.subscribe( "links", Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId);
    });

  //Nuke database helper function -- debugging
  Template.list_of_links.clean = function(collection) {
    if(collection) {
        // clean items
        _.each(collection.find().fetch(), function(item){
            collection.remove({_id: item._id});
        });
    }
  }

  //Songs from session
    Template.list_of_links.my_playlist = function () {
      return Links.find();
    };

    Template.search_bar.events({
    //http://stackoverflow.com/a/13945912/765409
    'keypress #query' : function (evt,template) {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (evt.which === 13){
        var url = template.find('#query').value;
        //Find a nicer way of clearing shit.
        $("#query").val('');
        Links.insert({sess:Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId,youtube_link:url});
        var cursor = Links.find();
        cursor.rewind();
        console.log(cursor.fetch());
        //Add to database.
    }
    }
  });  

  }

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    Meteor.publish("links", function( sess ) {
      return Links.find({sess: sess});  //each client will only have links with that _lastSessionId
    });
    //Making sure permissions are correct
Links.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    return true;
  }
}); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of behavior is expected when user doesn't have enough privileges to create a document. The insert function creates a local copy of the doc instantly (thanks to latency compensation), and then sync it with the result of server operation. If that operation fails, the temporary document is purged from client's Minimongo.

Have you created proper rules with `Collection.allow`? That's the first place to look for the cause.

Comment: I added a Links.allow call to the server code - I've updated the code above to reflect this, the results are unfortunately the same...

Comment: I cannot insert elements to the collection at all from the client. I removed the autopublish meteorite which I do not think should affect anything...

Comment: If you add back `meteor add insecure` what happens? If that works then your meteor allow rules aren't set properly

Comment: The result is the same. I found another oddity when I was trying to set a timeout that I marked as an update in the post, does this tell you anything new?

Comment: Your error is because you're not using `Meteor.setTimeout`, `setTimeout` doesn't use fibers. The second thing is you're using `Deps.autorun` even though there is nothing reactive in there. `Meteor.default_connection._lastSessionId` isn't reactive so it's not going to resubscribe when it changes.